# how can I replace characters which give me UnicodeDecoderErrors?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, data-extraction, unicode-string

I am extracting the content from different file types into a csv file.
I am currently trying to extract from the file type 'm'.
That's my extraction function:

```
def extract_m(f): # f is the file
    with open(f, encoding="utf8") as text:
       lines = text.read()
       lines = cleaning(lines)
       return lines
```

this code is working until some specific characters are in the document. Then my program throws out the *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte*

In some other file types the program was crashing when I tried to write the extracted data into the csv file. To fix that I used the cleaning() function which replaced the troublesome characters.
But now the program crashes at the line *lines = text.read()*
So the program cannot go into the cleaning() function.

I tried
`text = f.read().decode(errors='replace')`

But then I get the Error *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'*

I don't know why my function cannot open the file anymore.

Edit: You were all correct. One of the files is encoded in cp 1252.
When I put the
`errors='replace`
in
`open`
, then it is opening without error but '�'-symbols.

Comment: Put `errors='replace'` in the `open`, but if you are getting errors, the file is probably not encoded in UTF8

Comment: Are you sure the files are actually encoded as UTF-8?  UTF-8 will decode all ASCII characters, it sounds like the files (or some of them) may be encoded in an 8-bit encoding like latin-1 or cp1252.

Comment: The cause of the error is that your file is _not_ UTF-8. For a start, extract a [mcve] and provide the full exception (incl. traceback) that it produces. Use that error message to do some research as well. Look at the surrounding text, maybe you can guess the correct letter from that context. That would allow you to make a better guess at the encoding. Also, read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```py
def extract_m(f): # f is the file
    with open(f, encoding="utf8", errors='replace') as text:
       lines = text.read()
       lines = cleaning(lines)
       return lines
```

Where `errors` can be the following ones ([from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)):

- `'strict'` to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.
- `'ignore'` ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.
- `'replace'` causes a replacement marker (such as '?') to be inserted where there is malformed data.
- `'surrogateescape'` will represent any incorrect bytes as low surrogate code units ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. These surrogate code units will then be turned back into the same bytes when the surrogateescape error handler is used when writing data. This is useful for processing files in an unknown encoding.
- `'xmlcharrefreplace'` is only supported when writing to a file. Characters not supported by the encoding are replaced with the appropriate XML character reference &#nnn;.
- `'backslashreplace'` replaces malformed data by Python’s backslashed escape sequences.
- `'namereplace'` (also only supported when writing) replaces unsupported characters with \N{...} escape sequences.